# Wrong results from THD calculation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have measured signals (grid voltages and currents at 50Hz) of which I want to calculate the THD in MATLAB. However, using `thd(signalVector, samplingFrequency, numberOfHarmonics)` gives completely wrong results.
See the attached screenshot: The measured signal is on the left, the middle plot shows the FFT, on the right there is a closeup view of the FFT. As you can see, the THD is calculated to be too high at 86%:

[image: measured signal and calculated fft]

Looking at the `thd()` itself, it obviously mismatches the FFT:

[image: result from thd]

I used both `fft()` and `thd()` like in the MATLAB examples.
For `FFT` I use:

```
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L);
Y = fft(signal_vector,NFFT)/(samples_vector);
f = sampling_frequency/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);
y_fft = 2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1));
plot(f,y_fft)
```

For `THD` up to the 40. harmonic I simply use:

```
thd(signal_vector,sampling_frequency,40)
```

where sampling frequency is 40kHz.

I guess I am doing something essentially wrong. Where is the flaw?
Do you need additional information? Any help is appreciated (I hope this is the right place for my question)

EDIT: Using a [THD function from the Matlab File Exchange](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40455-computes-the-total-harmonic-distortion--thd--of-a-signal) I get a THD of 1.78%, but I do not know if this is correct, but seems realistic.

Comment: @howlger: Thanks for embedding the pictures!